# Inexplicable lack of internal storage on Asus TF701T tablet

Tags: cyanogenmod, internal-storage, asus-transformer-infinity

I own an Asus tablet, model TF701T 32GB internal memory. The tablet is rooted and contains the last snapshot build of Cyanogenmod 11 (Android 4.4.4). The tablet works well without any issues except the free space in internal memory.

The problem is that there is only 600MB of free space as shown in the screenshot but the summed space of all items is much less than 32GB.

[image]

Note that the ratio of available storage (Beschikbaar) is weird. The gray bar is longer than the green bar while green means 8,79GB and gray 603MB only.

Things that I tried already:

- Cleaning the tablet by using Clean Master Phone Boost
- Booting in recovery mode and wipe cache and dalvik cache
- Using root explorer to show properties of the content of the internal storage and the app displayed approximately 9GB of total content.

I installed pretty much games on the tablet that can explain 8,79GB of apps and its data and some megabytes of pictures on the tablet but what will eat up the other 16GB memory? Last week my free space was 5GB and without installing any new apps it dropped down to 603MB now.

Does anybody know how to find why this 16GB of memory is lost and how to empty this memory?

I scanned my internal storage with the app DiskUsage and the result is:

[image]

Comment: download this app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.diskusage post a screenshot of it scanning your internal story

Comment: Thank you for this tip, I posted the result of the scan.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. The directory /data/gps/log/ contained 16GB of log files and I could delete all of this files by using root explorer. I didn't delete the folder but empty the folder.